# Amazon MWS Products API - Where to find 'Important Information' section of a listing

Tags: amazon-mws

**Background:** Modernizing a clients seller account, need to programmatically get all listing information for their current listings.

**Progress:** Made use of the Reports API ('_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_') to get all listing skus (plus some of the needed info), starting on products API ('GetMatchingProductForId') to get the rest.

**Issue:** There seems to be information on a normal amazon.com front-end listing page that neither appears from the active listings report TSV nor in the XML from the Products API.

---

I've been searching and most of the responses I'm finding (from 2012) suggest using an AWS Product Advertising API for associate sellers to get more data (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html), but also caveat that Amazon was scuttling some of the data access from there (looking over the docs it also seems like a less than ideal solution for my use case).

I'd like to avoid page scraping an enormous amount of listings, and I feel like I have to be missing something in terms of API capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what amounts to an answer and want to leave it here in case it can save someone else the time I spent digging around in API docs. You can't get all the data you sent to amazon back again, they expect for you to keep records of your own listings (which is entirely reasonable).

You can, however, request a detailed report from their support team and get more data than the API itself will give you.

We ended up pulling what we could and building a new listings database, then updated our listings to match the database. This required more work up front, but gave us a more stable platform to work from in the future.